# Convert Matlab based Ridge Segment Function into C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am going to perform ridge segmentation on an input image using OpenCV. From the internet, I found a Matlab code as follows, which fits quite well with my goal:

```
function [normim, mask, maskind] = ridgesegment(im, blksze, thresh)

    im = normalise(im,0,1);  % normalise to have zero mean, unit std dev

    fun = inline('std(x(:))*ones(size(x))');

    stddevim = blkproc(im, [blksze blksze], fun);

    mask = stddevim > thresh;
    maskind = find(mask);

    % Renormalise image so that the *ridge regions* have zero mean, unit
    % standard deviation.
    im = im - mean(im(maskind));
    normim = im/std(im(maskind));
end
```

So I tried to convert it to C++. Up to now, I can only finish these parts:

```
cv::Mat ridgeSegment(cv::Mat inputImg, int blockSize, double thresh)
{
    cv::normalize(inputImg, inputImg, 0, 1.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
    blkproc(inputImg, cv::Size(blockSize, blockSize), thresh);
    ...// how to do the next steps ????
}

cv::Mat blkproc(cv::Mat img, cv::Size size, double thresh)
{
    cv::Mat croppedImg;
    for (int i = 0; i < im.cols; i += size.width)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < im.rows; j += size.height)
        {
            croppedImg = im(cv::Rect(i, j, size.width, size.height)).clone();

            //perform standard deviation calculation here???
        }
    }

    return croppedImg;
}
```

I don't know how to proceed further here. Especially that `stddevim` and its later parts. Could someone explain and show me the rest? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Compute the standard deviation of each sub-image with the given block-size

Comment: yeah, I know that part. how about the rest?

Comment: find all pixel where the block-std-dev is bigger than some threshold. compute the mean and stddev of those pixel and "apply" them to image: each pixel = (pixel-mean)/stddev.
Or is your question how to compute the stddev? Use http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#meanstddev .

Comment: Tipp: you can remove the `.clone()` if you dont want to alter the pixel values in your processing (which you dont have to). In your loop you will have to check whether the rect is legal (e.g. is completely within the image), otherwise it will crash. And I dont know whether blkproc uses overlapping blocks oder tiles (your code uses tiles).